# Can't receive touch events from UIButtons placed ontop of GMSMapView

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, touch-event, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to place some static UI such as buttons on top of google maps.

Currently for the screen I have

UIView
   - GMSMapView 
   - UIView 
      - UIButton

I changed the second UIView's layer.zPosition so that the view and button would show up, but I can't receive any touch events (touchupinside) from the UIButton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have to change the `UIView.zPosition` given your set up. I would take a second look at the point in your code when you add the second UIView, since the ordering that you call each view will matter if the `GMSMapView` and `UIView` are going to be at the same subview level.

Meaning, the UIView can be potentially be obstructed by some layer of the `GMSMapView`. (*Take note, that the `GMSMapView` is made of several layers, and it's very possible that the `GMSUISettings` layer is intercepting the touch events for the button*)

I made a very simple test app using google's sample code ([see here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#add_a_map)) plus the code for a UIView and UIButton:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     // Exact google code
     GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                        longitude:151.20
                                                             zoom:6];
     mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
     mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
     self.view = mapView_;

     // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
     GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
     marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
     marker.title = @"Sydney";
     marker.snippet = @"Australia";
     marker.map = mapView_;

    // UIView code
    UIView * buttonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 25, 150, 100)];
    [buttonView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [mapView_ addSubview:buttonView];

    // UIButton code
    UIButton * tapMe = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [tapMe setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 50)];
    [tapMe setTitle:@"Tap me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [tapMe setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [tapMe setBackgroundColor: [UIColor blueColor]];
    [tapMe addTarget:self action:@selector(tapButton:)      
                forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [buttonView addSubview:tapMe];
}
```

---

**Other Possible fix**
You can try to add the following code after you instantiate the `GMSMapView`:

```
    GMSUISettings * settings = mapView_.settings;
    [settings setConsumesGesturesInView:NO];
```

If there is a layer that intercepts touches, the [`setConsumesGesturesInView:`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_u_i_settings#a18ee69e2a06e4934beb9103663d6a73f) should have the same effect as `cancelsTouchesInView` in that your button will still receive touch events despite being behind the `GMSUISettings` layer.

---

What my sample looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Louis! I tried [settings setConsumesGesturesInView:NO] and it works. I'm new to iOS so I didn't know about the debug view that inspects different layers. The layers for my screen looked similar to yours but didn't work without setConsumesGestureinView, however after I recreated the UIViews & buttons again and it seems to work properly without it. But its definitely helpful to know theres a option in case I need it again :)